# WP plugins for Product web catalog

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to build website using wordpress.

There are tons of usable plugins, but instead of trying them all one by one id rather ask someone who can suggest me the one that would fit my needs.

The website is for small company who sells car scales.

I need multilanguage support(for 3languages) A plugin for displaying the products with category tree. When you click on the thumbnail it opens a picture(litebox style) with a short description and a little pdf icon as a pdf manual attachment.

It isnt suppose to be a webstore, but it would be nice if under the picture there would be a link("Please tell me more") or something like that and when you click on it it opens a contact form so if people want more information, like prices, guarantee, etc they will contact the administrator.

I understand that only plugins wont cover it and some php editing would be needed, but atleast I want to know with what to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your position, I'd use custom post types and taxonomies. I could recommend the following:

- [Custom Metadata Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-metadata/)
- [Ultimate Post Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-post-type-manager/)
- [Ultimate Taxonomy Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-taxonomy-manager/)

With these you can implement a post-like group, for example products, and category-like taxonomy, for example brands.

Multi language support is a lot trickier, however, I have good experiences with:

- [xili-language](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xili-language/)

For thumbnails, use post thumbnail function, it can be enabled in your theme init with:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Ray, peter did a great job of wrapping some things up for you, however I'd like to chime in as well and get you started in a couple areas that you don't really need a plugin's support for. However nice, it's not quite needed for some things. (Depending on skill, of course proceed at your own risk).

This is the code used to create your Custom Post Type `Products` this will allow to further customize the output of this piece of your WordPress site of course I suggest reading the [Codex Link about Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), as well as this one about [Querying your loops for URL REWriting](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api)

`add the following code to your themes functions.php file or in a plugin:`

```
    function wpse3242_product_posttype() {

        register_post_type( 'products',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Product' ),
                    'add_new' => __( 'New Product' ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Product' ),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product' ),
                    'new_item' => __( 'New Product' ),
                    'view_item' => __( 'View Products' ),
                    'search_items' => __( 'Search Products' ),
                    'not_found' => __( 'No Products found' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Products found in trash' )
                ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'publicly_queryable' => true,
                    'exclude_from_search' => false, // lets not guess what this will be, lets be authorative
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'show_in_menu' => true,
                    'query_var' => 'products',
                    'capability_type' => 'post',
                    'has_archive' => true,
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments'),
                    'rewrite'    => array(
                      'with_front'    => true,
                      'pages'         => true,
                      'feeds'         => false,
                      'slug'          => 'products',
                    ), 
               ) );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'wpse3242_product_posttype' );
```

Here's the code to make your Taxonomy for your `Item Tags & Categories`, these can later be used to sort through however you see fit, I've generalized the bit of code so hopefully you can understand how to use it for your needs. I would read about [Taxonomies from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) to understand how they interact with the WordPress machine.

`add the following code to your themes functions.php file or in a plugin:`

```
    function wpse3242_part_type_tax() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                          => 'Item Manager',
        'singular_name'                 => 'Item',
        'search_items'                  => 'Search Items',
        'popular_items'                 => 'Popular Items',
        'all_items'                     => 'All Items',
        'parent_item'                   => 'Last Item',
        'edit_item'                     => 'Edit Item',
        'update_item'                   => 'Change Item',
        'add_new_item'                  => 'Add Item',
        'new_item_name'                 => 'Create Item',
        'separate_items_with_commas'    => 'Separate Items with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'           => 'Add or remove Items',
        'choose_from_most_used'         => 'Choose from most used Items'
        );

    $args = array(
        'label'                         => 'items',
        'labels'                        => $labels,
        'public'                        => true,
        'hierarchical'                  => true,
        'show_ui'                       => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'             => true,
        'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'title' ),
        'rewrite'                       => array( /*'slug' => 'item', if you get into some advanced url-rewriting you may use this in some fashion */ 'with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => true ),
        'query_var'                     => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'items', array( 'products' ), $args );
    }

    add_action('init', 'wpse3242_part_type_tax');
```

This is by far no means to a complete answer, but hopefully it may be enough to get you pointed in the right directions.

Cheers!